# Scraping Thumbnail from NYtimes

Tags: php, web-scraping, pinterest

My scraping code works for just about every site i've come accross while testing... except for nytimes.com articles. I use ajax with the following PHP code (i've left out some details to focus on my specific problem):

```
$link = "http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/07/us/huge-leak-of-coal-ash-slows-at-north-carolina-power-plant.html?hp";
$article = new DOMDocument;
$article->loadHTMLFile($link);
//generate image array
$images = $article->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach ($images as $image) {
     $source = $image->getAttribute("src");
     echo '<img src="' . $source . '" alt="alt"><br><br>'; 
}
```

My problem is that the main images on nytimes pages don't even seem to get picked up by the getElementsByTagName. Pinterest finds a way to scrape the main images from this site for example: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/07/us/huge-leak-of-coal-ash-slows-at-north-carolina-power-plant.html?hp whereas I cannot. Any suggestions?

Comment: I hope your link is http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/07/us/huge-leak-of-coal-ash-slows-at-north-carolina-power-plant.html and not what you'ev given here

Comment: the reason $link is a variable is because I have it receives data from ajax that the user puts into a form. But sure, I've added the link in explicitly for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So this is what I tried so far as I found your question interesting.

When I do this on browser console using jQuery, I do get results on images. My query was

```
var a= new Array(); 
$('img[src]').each(function(){ a.push($(this).attr('src'));});
console.log(a);
```

Also see screenshot of results [image: here]

Note that `console.log(arrayname)` work in Chrome browser.

So ideally your code must work. Please consider adding a `is_null` check like I've done.

Below is the code where I try loading the URL using a different approach(perhaps better too) and get the root cause of why you get only single image of NYT logo.

The resultant HTML screenshot is attached [image: here].

```
<?php

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/07/us/huge-leak-of-coal-ash-slows-at-north-carolina-power-plant.html?hp");
    echo $html;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover=true;
    @$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>".$html."</body></html>");
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $images = $xpath->query("//*/img");
    if (!is_null($images)) {
    echo sizeof($images);
    foreach ($images as $image) {
         $source = $image->getAttribute('src');
         echo '<img src="' . $source . '" alt="alt"><br><br>'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

You can't get the content via feed unless you are authenticated.
You can try-

1. To use context parameter in `file_get_contents` method
2. You can try consuming the RSS/ATOM feeds of the article.
3. you download the page as HTML and then load it in `file_get_contents` methods. PS: This  works.

Comment: Is there a way that I can automate the process of downloading the page as html? For example could I automatically download the remote file to a tmp folder on my server and load it from there without going to the NYtimes page manually?

Comment: You can use Selenium plugin in Firefox for scraping images as well web pages directly from browser using stored scripts. A single Selenium plugin(once created offline) can be run over many sites by passing site name as parameters.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check out selenium. Unfortunately I am creating a web app scraper (like pinterest) so that users can do this automatically. I think I might just have to use the nyt api...